# Identification of special numbers based on recursive formula (combinatorics)

Tags: binomial-distribution, combinatorics

I am in the middle of a development and I stumbled on recursively defined numbers. They don't ring a bell for me, but maybe they were already studied. Anybody has a hint?

$$
\kappa^{(k+1)}_{\delta} 
= \sum_{\beta = 1}^{\delta-k}\kappa^{(k)}_{\delta - \beta}\binom{\delta}{\beta}
= \sum_{\beta' = k}^{\delta-1}\kappa^{(k)}_{\beta'}\binom{\delta}{\beta'}
$$

with $\kappa^{(1)}_{\delta}=1$ for all $\delta$. At the beginning, they are pretty manageable. E.g.
$$
\kappa^{(2)}_{\delta} = 2^{\delta} - 2
$$
$$
\kappa^{(3)}_{\delta} = 3(3^{\delta-1} - 2^{\delta} + 1 )
$$

I'm still working on finding a general solution for those numbers but I was wondering if they looked familiar to anybody.

A straightforward consequence of their definition is
$$
\kappa^{(\delta)}_{\delta} = \delta\kappa^{(\delta - 1)}_{\delta - 1} = \delta!
$$

I suspect they have the property
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\delta} (-)^k\kappa^{(k)}_{\delta} = (-1)^\delta
$$

edit:
Those counts appear in the powers of mapping of subsets of a range $[0, D]$. You define $K^{(\alpha\beta)}$ with $\alpha > \beta$ as the function taking a pair of sets of size $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively and returning 1 when they intersect and 0 otherwise. Then you arrange all subsets of $[0, D]$ in a basis set so that you define $K$ as the matrix mapping all the subsets together (it is a triangular matrix). It is composed of many $K^{(\alpha\beta)}$ blocks. Those coefficient $\kappa^{(k)}_{\alpha-\beta}$ appear when you take the $k^{th}$ power of $K$. More precisely, using a kinda of notation shortcut
$$
K = \sum_{\alpha = 2}^D\sum_{\beta=1}^{\alpha-1} K^{(\alpha\beta)}
$$
and
$$
K^k = \sum_{\alpha = k+1}^D\sum_{\beta=1}^{\alpha-k} \kappa^{(k)}_{\alpha-\beta} K^{(\alpha\beta)}
$$

For two subsets $S, S'$ of the range $[0, D]$ with $S \subset S'$,  $K^k(S, S')$ counts the number of ways you can split $S'\setminus S$ in $k$ subsets exactly.

Comment: Often, combinatorial identities are obtained by counting something in two different ways.  Thus, if you would explain what you are counting you would increase the chance that someone would offer a good solution.

Comment: I added a description of where those coefficients come from

Comment: Ok, your comment clearly led me somewhere (thanks!), now I am not certain how to handle this question - is it still relevant or should I delete it?

Comment: @Wilmerton If you have found a solution to your own question I would recommend answering your own question, for the future reference of other people. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice @whuber of describing the combinatoric interpretation of $\kappa^{(k)}_{\alpha-\beta}$, I figured out the answer.

They corresponds to the [Stirling numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541790/counting-ways-to-partition-a-set-into-fixed-number-of-subsets), $S(n, k)$, with an extra factorial for the ordering of the partition selection
$$
\kappa^{(k)}_{\alpha-\beta} = k! S(n, k)
$$

It corresponds to the definition of [Triangle numbers](http://oeis.org/A019538), and are similar to the the [Worpitzky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Connection_with_Worpitzky_numbers).

Comment: This didn't help with my suspicion on the alternate sum though so I posted a sequel. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459101/alternate-sum-of-worpitzky-numbers-similar-to-stirling-numbers